# Missing parenthesis before function parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update some old code for a customer but I keep receiving missing `(` before function parameters in my log files.

```
function gmtToFloat(tc) {
      timecode = tc.toString();
      var hhd = parseFloat(timecode.slice(-6, -3));
      var mmd = parseFloat(timecode.slice(-2)) / 60;
      return (hhd + mmd);
}

var diff = 
    gmtToFloat({Data.Session.utc}) - gmtToFloat({Data.Session.ctc});

diff;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what Data.Session.utc returns? I think your problem comes from there but can't know for sure without more info. It seems to me that you pass an invalid value in the gmtToFloat function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
function gmtToFloat(tc) {
  timecode = tc.toString();
  var hhd = parseFloat(timecode.slice(-6, -3));
  var mmd = parseFloat(timecode.slice(-2)) / 60;
  return hhd + mmd;
}

var diff = gmtToFloat(Data.Session.utc) - gmtToFloat(Data.Session.ctc);
diff;
```

You have to change `gmtToFloat({ Data.Session.utc })` to `gmtToFloat(Data.Session.utc)`